# SQL Server: Convert datetime string to decimal and match Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a694d/10

I am trying to convert a date string to a decimal value and that value to match the value that Excel gives.  From the SQLFiddle, some values match but later down the list it is off by one.

I have tried 2 different approaches and still cannot find the right combination to get the number to match the number that excel produces.

Here is the query that I am running (from SQLFiddle):

```
SELECT 
date_as_nvarchar_max
,excel_value_as_number
,cast((cast(date_as_nvarchar_max as datetime)-'1899-12-30T00:00:00')AS NUMERIC(10, 2)) as test1
,cast((cast(date_as_nvarchar_max as datetime)-'1899-12-31T00:00:00')AS NUMERIC(10, 2)) as test2
,datediff(day, '1899-12-30T00:00:00', date_as_nvarchar_max) as test3
,datediff(day, '1899-12-31T00:00:00', date_as_nvarchar_max) as test4

FROM EXCEL_DATES
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the values that are off by one are dates before March 1st 1900.

This is because [Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year).

Answer (score 0):

I converted your `date_as_nvarchar_max` to a `datetime` in the `cross apply` just for a cleaner illustration

The trick is convert a datetime into a float and add 2, **HOWEVER**, add 1 if the date is less than 1900-03-01

**Example**

```
SELECT A.*
      ,Calculated = convert(float,B.D)+IIF(B.D < '1900-03-01',1,2)
FROM EXCEL_DATES A
Cross Apply (values (convert(datetime,date_as_nvarchar_max)) ) B (D)
```

**Returns**

[image]